# What is usefulness of W3C's "Semantic Data Extractor" in semantically correct XHTML CSS Development?

Tags: css, xhtml, w3c, semantic-markup

What is the usefulness of W3C's **Semantic Data Extractor**?

http://www.w3.org/2003/12/semantic-extractor.html

> This tool, geared by an XSLT
>   stylesheet, tries to extract some
>   information from a HTML semantic rich
>   document. It only uses information
>   available through a good usage of the
>   semantics defined in HTML.
>
> The aim is to show that providing a
>   semantically rich HTML gives much more
>   value to your code: using a
>   semantically rich HTML code allows a
>   better use of CSS, makes your HTML
>   intelligible to a wider range of user
>   agents (especially search engines
>   bots).
>
> As an aside, it can give clues to user
>   agents developers on some hooks that
>   could be interesting to add in their
>   product.

After checking validation for CSS and HTML. Should i go for Semantic Data Extractor tool.

What it does. and how it can improved our coding.? Is anyone using it?

And i check some site randomly with but with most of sites it gives error

```
Using org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
Exception net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "input" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "`</input>`". 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "input" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "`</input>`".
```

Is it possible to get validate every site with this tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After checking validation for CSS and HTML. Should i go for Semantic Data Extractor tool.

Probably not

> What it does.

Exactly what you quoted from its homepage.

> and how it can improved our coding.?

Other then hitting you over the head when you have problems counting heading levels; not a lot.

> And i check some site randomly with but with most of sites it gives error

It depends on well formed and sane input.